# Correlation between matrices in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have problems in using the `cor()` and `cor.test()` functions.

I just have two matrices (only numerical values, and the same number of
row and columns) and I want to have the correlation number and the 
corresponding p-value.

When I use `cor(matrix1, matrix2)` I get the correlation coefficients for all the cells.
I just want a single number as result of cor.

In additon when I do `cor.test(matrix1, matrix2)` I get the following error

```
Error in cor.test.default(matrix1, matrix2) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

How can I get p-values for matrices?

You find the simple tables I want to correlate here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/table_exp1_offline_MEANS.csv

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/table_exp2_offline_MEANS.csv

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want. When you say you just want one result for cor(matrix1, matrix2), are you trying to correlate (all the numbers in matrix1) with (all the numbers in matrix2)? In that case, you could try cor(as.vector(matrix1), as.vector(matrix2))

Comment: What is the p-value expected to show, precisely? (i.e., what hypothesis are you testing?)

Comment: No, I just want to correlate the two matrices in order to know how much similar they are. I don't want a comparison cell by cell. I just want as a result a single number from 0 to 1, like every pearson correlation does using two vectors in input. Any suggestion? The p-value I expect has to tell me the significance of the correlation.

Comment: Do you mean as in `cor(as.vector(matrix1), as.vector(matrix2))`?

Answer (score 15):

If you simply want to calculate the correlation between the two sets of values, ignoring the matrix structure, you can convert the matrices to vectors using `c()`. Then your correlation is computed by `cor(c(matrix1), c(matrix2))`.

Comment: Using your function I get this error: "Error in cor(c(matrix1), c(matrix2)) : 'x' must be numeric". But if you have a quick look at my tables you notice that they contains only numbers...I do not understand

Comment: An R issue this one: `read.csv`, which you probably used, returns a `data.frame` which is a not a `matrix`.  So you need to convert it to being a `matrix` with `as.matrix` before making it one long vector with `c()` and giving the results to `cor`.  Here it is in one line: `cor(c(as.matrix(matrix1)), c(as.matrix(matrix2)))`

Answer (score 8):

You haven't said anything about what your data actually is.  Nevertheless...

*Suppose* that your matrices have columns representing two sets of (different) variables and (the same number of) rows representing cases.

**Canonical Correlation Analysis**

In this situation, one potentially interesting more structured correlation analysis is to find the *canonical correlations*.  This assumes that you want to summarize the relationship between the two sets of variables in terms of the correlation(s) between linear combinations of `matrix1` columns and linear combinations of `matrix2` columns.  And you would want to do that if you suspected that there was a space of small dimensionality, perhaps even 1, that would reveal an underlying correlation structure across the cases that is obscured by their realization in the current variable-defined coordinate systems.  Consequently the value of this (canonical) correlation would, in a sense, summarize a multivariate linear relationship between the two matrices.  Indeed, while CCA works for matrices with different numbers of variables it reduces to Pearson correlation when each 'matrix' is just a single column.

**Implementation**

Canonical correlation analysis is described in most multivariate analysis texts, which is perhaps most helpful if you happy with matrix algebra up to eigenanalysis.  It is implemented as `cancor` in base R and also in the [CCA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CCA/index.html) package which is described [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v23/i12/paper).

Comment: Hi thanks. My data are simple two matrices containing the same variables. The structure of the two matrices is identical. The values in each cell are the results of an experiment where those variables were evaluated on a 9-points Likert scale and averaged across participants. Which is the best strategy to find in there is correlation between the two matrices? Can you make an example in R?

Comment: With base R it's just `cancor(matrix1, matrix2)`.

Comment: But perhaps you can clarify a bit.  Call `matrix1` $A$.  Then what is $A_{ij}$? Is it the $i$-th person's reponse to the $j$-th Likert item?  Surely not.  So where does the average over participants come in?

Comment: Hi there were 10 participants, they had to express the "degree of coherence" between pairs stimuli (note it is not a dissimilarity rating experiment). I did 2 experiments. and I want to compare the results under the 2 expdrimental conditions. Each cell is the average of the evaluations of the 1o participants for each pair of stimuli. Then should I still use cancor?

Comment: I used cancor, but I do not get a single coefficient value expressing the correlation nor a p-value expressing its significance. Please help!

Comment: Now it doesn't sound like cancor is what you want at all.

Comment: It might be best if you describe the experiment first.  I gather: 10 participants rate the degree of something across (all pairwise?) combinations of (five?) stimuli in two conditions. And you're interested in the difference in the something between conditions.  Try adjusting your question to include a filled-in version of that.  Then we'll know enough to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi, cor.test(c(as.matrix(matrix1)), c(as.matrix(matrix2))) works perfectly.  I gathered 10 participants, evaluating the degree of coherence of two stimuli presented in succession on a 9 points likert scale (36 pairs, 6 stimuli compared with the same 6 stiumuli) I have 2 conditions. The results for each pair is shown in the matrices: each cell is the average of all the 10 participants evaluations for each pair of stimuli.

Answer (score 4):

If you loosely construe correlation to mean similarity, you can use a definition based on the inner product, such as:

$c_{AB} = \dfrac{\langle A, B \rangle}{\|A \| ||B\|}$ where $\langle A,B \rangle \equiv \mathrm {tr}(A B^T)$ and $\| x || \equiv \langle x,x \rangle^{1/2}$

With your data this yields 0.996672.

The alternative, if the matrix structure is not important, is to simply flatten the matrices into vectors and use the correlation measure of your choice. Since I don't know your data's distribution I used the dot product, to get 0.976.

Eithe3r way, it seems your data is highly correlated.

Comment: This seems the [rv coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RV_coefficient), which is what the OP asked: a value between 0 and 1 that tells how similar both matrices are.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into fast distance covariance and correlation
which I think R probably has an implementation of.

The answers above have details for R programming to get the
Pearson correlation coefficient which is what you asked for.
To explore distance correlation here is a quick summary of
some steps you could take. The code is in java, but you could port
it to R.

To only calculate the correlation between the the same column
in each of the 2 datasets of the
same size and number of variables, matrix1 and matrix2,
you are calculating only the diagonal of a full correlation matrix.
And you are wanting to combine those correlations into
one number to use as a replacement for similarity between the
2 matrices.

let x1 = matrix1 and x2 = matrix2 below

```
input: double[][] x1 and double[][] x2 being same size
double[][] dCor = zeros(x1[0].length, x2[0].length);
double[] tmp1 = new double[x2.length];
double[] tmp2 = new double[x2.length];
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < x1[0].length; ++i) {
    //for (j = 0; j < x2[0].length; ++j) {
        j = i
        // copy each column vector to calculate correlation
        for (k = 0; k < x2.length; ++k) {
            tmp1[k] = x2[k][j];
            tmp2[k] = x1[k][i];
        }
        // fast dcor runtime is O(n*log_2(n))
        dCor[i][j] = sqrt(fastDCor(tmp1, tmp2).corSq);
    //}
}
```

where fastDCor is fast distance correlation.
reference:

```
"A fast algorithm for computing distance correlation"
2019 Chaudhuri and Hu, Computational Statistics And Data Analysis,
Volume 135, July 2019, Pages 15-24.
```

For combining correlation0 with correlation 1 and correlation2 etc.
you could browse the short paper:

```
Charter and Alexander 1993, "A Note on Combining Correlations".
```

The paper details are for the Pearson correlation, but are informative.