# Correlation between two 2D arrays

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, cross-correlation, brownian-motion

I could not find anywhere, how to calculate correlation between two arrays. Say I do have Array1 with X and Y values and also Array2 with X and Y values. I tried to do some calculation and inserting two same arrays and expecting the correlation to be 1, but the result was something like -0.16...

I would be glad for any suggestion. Btw. I've found this [Correlation coefficient between two arrays of 2D points?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73805/correlation-coefficient-between-two-arrays-of-2d-points) but still didnt find anything what could help me.

Comment: To be clear, you want to compute the correlation between two matrices? Look into the [RV coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RV_coefficient), it is a multivariate extension of the R-squared.

Comment: Wel, I have two arrays full of data like this. [0] => Array ( [x] => 964 [y] => 844 ). The arrays are same size. And now I would like to find programmatically correlation between this. Was googling for RV coefficient matlab examples, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: I don't use MatLab, but you can do it in R using the `coeffRV` function in the `FactoMineR` package.

Answer (score 2):

An array with 2 dimensions is a matrix. Since your arrays have 2 dimensions, you are looking to find the correlation between these two matrices.

Here is a question with answers in R: "[Correlation between matrices in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24980/correlation-between-matrices-in-r)"

Here is a question with answers in MATLAB:  "[Matlab correlation between two matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960218/matlab-correlation-between-two-matrices)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I dont understand, why in one example I am getting output one value and in the other example I am getting an output matrix. And also, should this 2D array be stored in matrix as MAT[vec2(X,Y), vec2(X,Y)....] and so? Or what is the best way to store these X and Y values in the matrix to pass to matlab for example?

Comment: For those answers you need to read the MATLAB's documentation for the function you are using. For instance, here is the documentation for the function "corrcoef": http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html